# Bubble plugin doesn't work

Tags: java, bukkit

Basically I'm trying to create a plugin that allows for the someone (that has perms) to do /bubble , and whoever's name corresponds to that name will get "bubbled". This bubble is basically a rejection field, (sphere) so whenever someone besides the args[0] (username to bubble) will get flung out very fast and abruptly. I don't know if you have ever seen this, but if you need more proof of concept, mineplex.com is a minecraft server that has this concept implemented into treasure chests. Basically whenever someone clicks on that, they become trapped in a 1x2 area, and everyone that tries to come withing 5 blocks of them gets shot out, kind of like them bouncing off. Here is the code I've come up with. I don't know why this doesn't work, there aren't any errors, but it doesn't fling them out.

NOTE: I'm using a main class that calls this one (the main class is called "Main". Also, This class is called "Bubble".

EDIT: I just updated the code to use hashmaps. They aren't currently implemented, but I would like to use them in the plugin.

```
package me.Glowhoo.EpicUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.metadata.FixedMetadataValue;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;
/*
 * Author =
 * Glowhoo
 * 
 */
public class Bubble implements CommandExecutor, Listener {
private Main plugin;

public Bubble(Main plugin)
{
  this.plugin = plugin;
}
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
{
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bubble"))
    {
        if (sender instanceof Player)
        {
            if (args.length > 0 && args.length <= 2)
            {
            if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]) != null)
            { //Note: I suck with hashmaps.
                HashMap<String, Boolean> bubbles = new HashMap<>(); //Attempted to make a hashmap of the player which has the bubble, and if the bubble is on/off.
                Player victim = (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]));
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.BOLD.GREEN + victim.getName() + ChatColor.BOLD.DARK_GRAY + " Is now in a bubble!");
                FixedMetadataValue metadataValue = new FixedMetadataValue((Plugin)this.plugin, true);
                victim.setMetadata("isInBubble", metadataValue);


                if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("on")) //i.e /bubble <username> <on/off>
                {
                bubbles.put(args[0], true);
                }else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("off"))
                {
                    bubbles.put(args[0], false);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player is not online!");

            }

            }
            else
            {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid arguments!");
            }


        }
        else
        {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "The console cannot bubble someone!");
        }

    }



    return false;
}
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
     Player mover = e.getPlayer();
     Location from = e.getFrom();
     Location to = e.getTo();
     Collection<Entity> nearbyEntities = mover.getWorld().
     getNearbyEntities(from,  10, 10, 10);//Get entities in a 10 block square from loc "from"
     List<Player> nearbyPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
     for (Entity en : nearbyEntities) {
         if (en instanceof Player)
           nearbyPlayers.add((Player) en);
     }
     for (Player victim : nearbyPlayers) {
         if (victim.hasMetadata("isInBubble") && victim != mover) {
            Location victimLoc = victim.getLocation();
            if (victimLoc.distance(to) <= 5) {//Radius 5
                e.setCancelled(true); //Cancel so cant move
                return; //we have nothing left no need to get in for statement again
            }
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgot to add the `@EventHandler` annotation before `onPlayerMove` method.

You also need to register the `PlayerMoveEvent` in the plugin manager, so add the following code to your `onEnable()` method:

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, new Bubble());
```

If you would like to store the bubble statuses on players in a `HashMap`, you need to use a `HashMap<UUID, Boolean>` field, where you store the player UUIDs and the bubble toggled status.
You need to store the player when he joins and remove him when he quits the game.

Comment: You could also just use an `ArrayList<UUID>` instead of a `HashMap<UUID, Boolean>`. Instead of setting the HashMap value to false, remove from the List, and instead of setting the HashMap value to true, add to the List.